# Angular 7 build--prod generated files

Tags: angular, webpack, build, angular-cli, production

Im facing an issue with the resulting files from the build prod process on an angular7 app:

the build prod is done with the following flags:

```
ng build myApp --aot=true --progress=false --base-href=/app-ng/ --output-path=dist/ --prod --configuration=production --output-hashing=none
```

Because of diferents requirements the route where the index fetches the vendor.js, main.js files etc needs to be modified like the following:

from:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PeopleOs</title>
  <base href="/app/">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/ui/design/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/ui/design/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/ui/design/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../conference-ng/styles.a4bd136a77b52601cadb.css"></head>
<body>
  <pplos-root></pplos-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.dcdd77c06796f7b1eee4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.6c7e1fff37149795538b.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/main.134c83da3aea9780ff98.js"></script></body>
```

to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PeopleOs</title>
  <base href="/app/">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/ui/design/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/ui/design/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/ui/design/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../conference-ng/styles.a4bd136a77b52601cadb.css"></head>
<body>
  <pplos-root></pplos-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app-ng/runtime.dcdd77c06796f7b1eee4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../app-ng/polyfills.6c7e1fff37149795538b.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../app-ng/main.134c83da3aea9780ff98.js"></script></body>
```

Notice the change on the src from where the index fetches the bundle files

This works great, but angular 7 is building an extra file that i cannot identify and its not fetched from index.html but fetched from somewehere else. Since im not able to modify the url for that file as i do with the others this fetch ends up on an error.

This is the output from the build process:

```
Date: 2019-07-11T13:04:42.096Z
Hash: 85d1d51fc7a58f145037
Time: 109542ms
chunk {0} runtime.js (runtime) 2.11 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.js (main) 82 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.js (polyfills) 114 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.css (styles) 37.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} vendor.js (vendor) 1.11 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.js () 405 kB  [rendered]
```

This "5.js" is the one that im not able to identify neither modify how its retrieved on runtime by the index.html. I checked it an it contains constants files and components from modules of my angular app.

- Is it possible to bundle this file into vendor.js or main.js and get rid of it ?
- There is a way to specify a common url prefix that is attached to all files fetches (and also to the 5.js one) ? ex: '../app-ng/' moved to a angular.json or webpack config variable
- Any other idea that would help here ?

The app is running under certain NGINX rules that make this files fetching possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's a lazy loaded module? Try adding `--namedChunks=true` to your command line, you should be able to see real file names

Comment: thats it, is the file for a lazy loaded module :) any chance to set a custom path from where to load lazy modules from ?

Answer (score 0):

You an use the `deploy-url` option to specify where to load js/css files files from

```
ng build ... --deploy-url ../app-ng
```